# how to increase maxTextMessageBufferSize value for websockets?

Tags: java, websocket, jetty

I need to increase to increase the max text message buffer size of websockets. I need to send many messages which are too large.
Please do you have any suggestions how to do so?

Comment: What framework are you using for websockets?

Comment: org.eclipse.jetty.websocket

Answer (score 0):

When you use Jetty's default WebSocketServletFactory like...

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory factory) {
    factory.getPolicy().setIdleTimeout(600000);
    factory.register(Socket.class);
}
```

you can simple change the message buffer size in...

```
factory.getPolicy().setMaxTextMessageBufferSize(int size);
```

See also whole API: [apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/api/WebSocketPolicy](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.4.0.v20161208/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/api/WebSocketPolicy.html#setMaxTextMessageBufferSize-int-)

Here are more informations about jetty's websocket-server:
[eclipse.org/jetty/documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/jetty-websocket-server-api.html)